# Color switching in Unity (with script)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to increase alpha channel on every hit taken by an object. But i cant use my Alpha variable as it's an `integer` and `color32` needs byte value.  I know about `color`, which is float, but it's not working for me, I need `color32`. How can i do that?

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {

        Alpha += 255 / maxHits;
        currentHit++;
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = new Color32(159,86,86,Alpha);
        if (currentHit == maxHits) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
}
```

Comment: So why do you declare `Alpha` as `int` instead of `byte`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure Alpha is a float. try this:

```
float Alpha = 0;

void OnCollisionEnter2D (Collision2D col) {

        Alpha += 1f / maxHits;
        currentHit++;
        gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().color = new Color(159f/255,86f/255,86f/255,Alpha);
        if (currentHit == maxHits) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very meaningfull that you can only plug in alpha values which are a `byte`, i.e. between 0 and 255. That's because the used color system (24 bit RGBA) has exactly 8 bits/1 byte per color channel. It doesn't make sense to try and plug in values above 255 or below 0.

When you can make sure that your `Alpha` variable has meaningful values between 0 and 255, just cast it to a byte by prepending `(byte)` in front of it, or directly declare `Alpha` to be of type `byte`. That's it.